# How many “as”es are required in “as X as Y”?

Tags: comparative-constructions

I used the following expression:

> As far I can see, I’m godlike.

A colleague of mine opposed that statement, not on semantic grounds (he *does* know I'm godlike, although he'd never admit that), but rather due to grammatical inconsistency with his experience. He proposes that the *only* correct way to express that form is with an extra *as*, like so:

> As far as I can see, I’m godlike.

Is he correct? (Please keep in mind that I’m godlike, hence unlikely to err.)

Comment: As near as I can figure, you've got it wrong. I've never heard it without the other *as*.

Comment: Omitting the second ***as*** was [more common 2-3 centuries ago](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+far+I+can&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20far%20I%20can%3B%2Cc0), but relatively speaking [it was always an extremely rare usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+far+I+can%2Cas+far+as+I+can&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20far%20I%20can%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20far%20as%20I%20can%3B%2Cc0). I would say this is General Reference.

Comment: There should be two *as*'s, because that's the way [the equative construction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/118055/15299) is constructed; only two phrases, each one marked with _as_ at the beginning. The second _as_ may well be dying in various Englishes world wide, but it's the norm for native speakers in the USA.

Comment: @JohnLawler Sometime the first one is skipped in sentence-initial position in relaxed speech: *Far as I can see, there ain’t nothin’ to be done here.*  And then there’s the *It’s not so far as you’d think* variant.

Comment: @tchrist: Right. This is true of **any** predictable sentence-initial material -- determiners, auxiliaries, prepositions, complementizers, pronouns, you name it -- under the rule of [Conversational Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find the phrase without the second "as" in any legitimate source (dictionary / grammar books).

A quick Google search shows that it is also *much* less frequent:

- 102,000,000 - "as far I"
- 1,010,000,000 - "as far as I"

If you examine the context in the "as far I" results, the overall quality of English is very poor, so it would seem safe to assume it's just wrong.

Comment: A google search will not tell you if something is correct or not. It will only tell you that there at least 102,000,000 illiterates in the world.

Comment: @fdb While agreeing with your point, I need to remark that being listed on google for something one's written, disqualifies said person from being **illiterate**, doesn't it? Perhaps a bad speller and less then fluent but definitely not an illiterate.

Comment: "Illiterate" is used here - as often - in its hyperbolic sense.

Comment: @KonradViltersten To pick nits, a written transcript of a conversation with an illiterate person can exist.

Comment: [COCA](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/) is way better than Google for this sort of thing. Everything on it is written or spoken by native speakers.

Comment: And Google books is much better than Google. As this answerer says, page through those millions of results – lots of hits on message boards with bad grammar, punctuation, or capitalization, like this gem: _as far i know the mac g5 have an 80 gb hd and 512 mb of ram but with an extra euros 70 i can buy a wd 320 gb hd and 1 gb ram..._

Comment: @JasonC Good point. I stand corrected. Not that anybody things should believe that there are 100+ millions transcripts of the illiterates' speech but that's beyond the point since I questioned the existence of **any** such. Nice nit-picking. :)

Comment: @J.R. Very good example of all things bad. However, suppose that you're a intergalactic traveler vising the Earth with no prior knowledge of it. Given that the number of such atrocities is large and growing (pessimistically presumably at a higher pace than the high quality production), one wonders what the visitor might get the impression of in regards to the correct English...

Comment: @Konrad - That's why you'll see some refer to _standard English_ or _formal English_ instead of _correct English_. What's unsuitable for a published paper may be perfectly natural in the corner bar – and perhaps vice-versa. In your specific case here, I, too, would advise you to use _as_ twice. I was amazed at how many instances I found with only one, but wondered how many of those were typos. Yet I find examples in books, too. From a 2001 non-fiction work:

Comment: _As President Franklin Roosevelt told the National Emergency Council on December 11, 1934, TVA was a social experiment that is the first of its kind in the world, **as far I know**, covering a convenient geographical area_. Strange. It appears some people find it natural to omit the second _as_. If you wanted to hold your ground, there's plenty of precedent to stand on.

Comment: As a non-NSE I believe I can provide an explanation for why people might have the impression that it's correct to omit the second "*as*".  Note that you can omit the bold word in the following sentence. "*The girl **whom** I date is cute.*" The omission rendering "*The girl I date is cute.*" is (in my mind) perceived **as** grammatically equivalent to "*As far **that** I can see.*" rendering "*As far **that** I can see.*" because it's sort-of "*The furthest **that** I can see.", still omitting the bold *that*. Also, notice the bold (and indeed omissible) *as* in my sentence after *perceived*.